# invalid markup marked invalid because it contains a duplicate attribute

Tags: dreamweaver

I'm editing an HTML file in Dreamweaver CS4, the website looks good if I run it in firefox but I'm getting this error:
"invalid markup marked invalid because it contains a duplicate attribute"

Here is the code: the highlighted one is the one being shown in Dreamweaver.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Template 3 - Left Sidebar</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
  body {
     margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url('bg.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-y no-repeat;
    background-color: #8da2b2;
    background-position: top center;
  }

  p {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #333333;
  }

  li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  td.permission {
     padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  }

  td.permission p {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #4c4c4c;
    margin: 0 0 4px 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }

  td.permission p.second {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
  }

  td.permission a {
    color: #000000;
  }

  td.header {
    background-color: #b73224;
    height: 110px;
  }

  td.header h1 {
    font-family: Impact, 'Arial Black';
    font-size: 33px;
    color: #eaedc9;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 28px;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    padding: 0;
  }

  td.sidebar a img {
    border: none;
  }

  .table {
    background-color: #a52c21;
  }

  td.miniTable {
    background-color: #a52c21;
    padding: 20px;
  }

  td.miniTable h2 {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  td.miniTable h3 {
     font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  td.miniTable h3 a {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }

  td.miniTable p {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #e7fccf;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  td.miniTable ul {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #e7fccf;
    margin: 0 0 0 24px;
    padding: 0;
  }

  td.miniTable ul li a {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #e7fccf;
     text-decoration: none;
  }

  td.mainbar h2 {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000000;
    border-left: 10px solid #a02f27;
    padding-left: 8px;
  }

  td.mainbar h2 a {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  td.mainbar a {
    color: #344692;
  }

  td.mainbar p {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  }

  td.mainbar p.top {
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
  }

  td.mainbar p.top a {
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 0 4px 0 0;
  }

  td.mainbar img.inline {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  }

  td.footer {
    height: 134px;
  }

  td.footer p {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #333333;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
  }

  table.tab {
    background-image: url('footer-bg.gif');
    background-rep
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duplicate specification of attribute "ALIGN"

```
<td align="center" align="134" class="footer" valign="bottom">
```

UPDATE: I used the online tool from http://validator.w3.org/check

Comment: thanks for the info Nicu Zecheru. Do I have to copy all the HTML code? and paste it on the address tab of the validator website? 
this is very helpful.

Comment: you have 3 options: Validate by URI (http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_uri), file upload (http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload) or direct input (http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input):

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, the line of code you highlighted:

```
<td align="center" align="134" class="footer" valign="bottom">
```

has the `align` attribute set twice. The second (`134`) isn't a valid value for `align`.

Outside that, though, you've actually got a number of other problems:

- you're using the tags `<forwardtoafriend>`, `<unsubscribe>`, `<subscribe>`, and `<webversion>`—but none of them are part of any HTML standard, and therefore aren't understood by browsers.
- You have no opening `<body>` tag.
- You aren't closing your `<meta>` or `<img>` tags.
- Your `background-repeat: repeat-y no-repeat;` style rule for `body` is invalid; it should only have a single value (in this case, `background-repeat: repeat-y`).
- You start off with

  ```
   <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
       <tr>
           <td align="center">
  ```

  followed by another internal table. That's fine, but then when you close the internal table, you have another `<tr>` when you need to end your previous `<td>` and `<tr>` first. And after that last row, you have a closing `</td>` that doesn't match any previous `<td>`.
- At the  end, you're missing the tags:

  ```
          </table>
      </body>
  </html>
  ```
- Some other quibbles:

  - you should have a `doctype`
  - `<table>` doesn't have a height attribute
  - some of your `<img>` tags are missing `alt` attributes

You say you're using Dreamweaver CS4, but I've never seen it produce that kind of output before…

Comment: hi Dori thanks for the input, i got this html from the website, its a template. I would like to design a newsletter and don't know where to start. so i decided to download some samples newsletter and would like to give it a try with dreamweaver or more or less edit it from there. i don't have a strong background with css & php though but i am a quick learner once i know the functions.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to find out whats wrong with your html code to validate it here http://validator.w3.org.

Comment: thanks too. I just played around and found out that the align="134" is the problem. When I deleted it, it solved the problem. But how can I validate it in the validator site? Do I have to copy all the html code?